# How to display multiple images upload and display in php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, magento, innerhtml

I have used magento extension to prepare in older version 1.3.2.4.In this I have used to upload mutliple products images upload and displayed.

So, Can you give that suggest any idea about that?

Thanks.